# Keep duplicates which appear more than three times in SAS

Tags: sas

I know the code to keep all duplicates, but how can I only keep duplicates which appear more than three times in SAS?

```
proc sort
     data = test  out=want  nouniquekey  ;
     by var1 var2 var3 var4;
run;
```

Comment: Rephrase your question please, or supply example data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC SQL, group by var1-var4, keep those with > 3 records, then select all the corresponding records from the primary dataset.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select *
  from have
  where catx('_',var1,var2,var3,var4) in(select catx('_',var1,var2,var3,var4) as groupvar
                                         from have
                                         group by calculated groupvar
                                         having count(1) > 3)
  ;
quit ;
```

Comment: I think, but don't have time to check, that you don't actually need the `in` clause - SAS lets you sort of get that for free.